# LOGGER doesn't work in spring boot with Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, spring-boot, loggerfactory

I have developed a spring boot application in Microsoft azure with @ServiceBusTrigger. But in this logger is not working as expected.

I am using below function for this:

```
 @FunctionName("irn-generate")
public void serviceBusProcess(  @ServiceBusQueueTrigger(name = "msg", queueName = "queueName", connection = "connectionstring") String message,
  ExecutionContext context) {
    try {

        LOGGER.info("in logger string:{}",message.toString());
        context.getLogger().info(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    }

}
```

Here ,I am able to get log using context but how can I achieve this outside this function.
Can anyone help me to get out of this?

Comment: Please add some code, what you tried, what didn't work and what problems you get. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks for replying.I add the code snippet.Any suggestions on this?

Comment: What is ExecutionContext

Comment: @SimonMartinelli ExecutionContext is com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;

Comment: Ah and you want that to use to log. Are you using MVC or WebFllux?

Comment: Actually for logging purpose i am using org.slf4j.Logger. It works fine with AWS Lambda Function.But now I need to make my code compatible with Azure Function APP.In azure I am getting problem in logging.

Comment: What kind of Problem?

Comment: When I am checking logs of AZURE Function they are not getting printed.May I know what can be the problem?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Any suggestion on this from your side?

Comment: In my code   LOGGER.info("in logger string:{}",message.toString()); this didn't print anything.Any reason @SimonMartinelli